# Py2Exe Scikit-Image Compilation missing mkl_intel_thread.dll

Tags: python, python-3.4, py2exe

Using py2exe and Scikit-Image I am trying to compile an image editing program. 
My environment is Windows 10 64-bit 32gbs ram Intel i7 and 32-bit Python 3.4.
When I run

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

with this setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import scipy.linalg.cython_blas

opts = {"py2exe": {
"includes": ['scipy',
'scipy.linalg.cython_blas','scipy.linalg.cython_lapack','scipy.sparse.csgraph._validation','scipy.linalg']}}
setup(options=opts,console=['glitchArray.py'])
```

it compiles with this warning

```
Error: Namespace packages not yet supported: Skipping package 'mpl_toolkits'

  43 missing Modules
  ------------------
```

When I run the exe that is compiled and left in dist/ I get this:

```
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll.
```

This program runs perfectly in the interpreter but the executable does not except to throw the Intel FATAL ERROR.

Following this example [py2exe: MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34985134/py2exe-mkl-fatal-error-cannot-load-mkl-intel-thread-dll) also did not help.