# Cannot load mkl_init_thread.dll when running exe

Tags: python, dll, exe, py2exe

I used py2exe to create a few different exe's, one main GUI and two plotting functions that the GUI calls occasionally. When running them on my computer, there is no problem at all, but when I run them on other computers (the only reason I made them exe's was to do exactly this), I get the following error:

```
Intel MLK Fatal Error: Cannot load intel_mlk_thread.dll
```

I only get this error when my GUI calls on one of the plotting exe's. The dll in question is already saved in each of the "dist" folders that py2exe creates for each program, so [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34985134/py2exe-mkl-fatal-error-cannot-load-mkl-intel-thread-dll) is not a duplicate.

Any ideas?