# INTEL MKL ERROR: The specified module could not be found. mkl_intel_thread.1.dll. Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.1.dll

Tags: python, numpy, exe, intel-mkl, auto-py-to-exe

I want to create an .exe file from .py file using Auto Py To Exe. Everything works fine, file is created, but when I try to open it, I have an error:

```
INTEL MKL ERROR: The specified module could not be found. mkl_intel_thread.1.dll.
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.1.dll.
```

and then console goes down.

I tried to find it:

```
U:\>where mkl_intel_thread.dll
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

It seems like it doesn't exist on my computer.

How could I solve this problem?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Possible workarounds for your issue are given below:

1. Here the problem is it links to three separate libraries instead of one library or try setting the environment or do preload dll etc.

For Linux:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_def.so:/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_avx2.so:/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so:/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.so:/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so:/opt/intel/lib/intel64_lin/libiomp5.so
```

For Windows:
setting env by `mkl/bin/mklvars.bat intel64`, then run your python in same environment

**or**

in Python to add the library manually `sys.path.append(" your path to the library")`

2. Refer this:  [Pyinstaller numpy "Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35478526/pyinstaller-numpy-intel-mkl-fatal-error-cannot-load-mkl-intel-thread-dll)
3. [Manually copying the required dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34985134/py2exe-mkl-fatal-error-cannot-load-mkl-intel-thread-dll?rq=1) from inside numpy/core, into the dist folder that py2exe creates, not outside of it.

Refer this for more information:
https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Math-Kernel-Library/python-mkl-error/m-p/1163247